# Forms will not close completely and open without any reason

Tags: c#

My program has 2 forms and code for both of them when i start another form just hide form 1 and when i start form 1 hide form 2.
But this not happen and forms won't hide they just start again.
I put 2 buttons in each forms that when you click button on first form,the first form will Hide and the second form will show and when you click on the button in second form hide it and show the first form.
I could do it and it works fine.
But you can see my problem in picture.
You can see what am i talking in the picture that i uploaded

.[You can see my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh4z9.jpg)

This is my code in Button1 in form 1 :

```
    private void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 =new Form2();
        f2.Show(); // Shows Form2
    }
```

and this is my code in Button2 in Form 2:

```
    private void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                Form1 f1 = new Form1(); // Instantiate a Form3 object.
                f1.Show(); // Show Form3 and
                this.Close();
    }
```

I could solve one form and form number 2 don't open without result.
but when i write this code in button1 form 1 :

```
 this.Close();
```

After i click button 2 in form 2 application close and will not show form

---

I put the codes

```
public Form1 f1 { get; set; }
```

in form 2 and

```
public Form2 f2 { get; set; }
```

in form 1.

But i have that problem yet...
Error show me that 'f2' does not exist in the current context.

---

And this is class with method :(Form 2)

```
 private void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And Form 1:

```
private void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

---

This is exactly what i was searching for.
Thanks a lot VDN.

my problem solved.

Comment: It will be so much easier to help when you provide some code

Comment: can you show us your Form1 class with f1 property and only one method in it - btnMigrate_Click()  and Form2 class with f2 property and with the same method?

Comment: see my answer edits. That is how your classes and methods should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add references from one form to another, so you can change properties of one form from the other. Then, in button_click event you do not need to create a new instance of the other form each time, but you have to check if the form in the refference f1/f2 was not created before or was disposed (only in this case you need to create the form), and then show the other form and hide(but not close) the current one:

Form1 class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form2 f2 { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.f2 == null || this.f2.IsDisposed == true)
        {
            this.f2 = new Form2();
            this.f2.f1 = this;
        }
        f2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Form2 class:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form1 f1 { get; set; }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnMigrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.f1 == null || this.f1.IsDisposed == true)
            {
                this.f1 = new Form1();
                this.f1.f2 = this;
            }
            f1.Show();
            this.Hide();

        }
    }
```